# Understanding integral remainder for Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I understand the Taylor polynomial. But when I get to the integral's remainder, I can't understand what it represents. I'm asking if someone could give me a clear explanation on that, as on the internet all I encountered was Lagrange's form.

The remainder Rn for the MacLaurin's polynomial is given by:
$$\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{n}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt$$
There's three points that are intriguing me

1. Is it supposed to solve the integral?
2. Does the $x$ in the $(x-t)^n$ represents the same $x$ of the integral? I'm a bit confused about this.
3. In general I don't understand what am I supposed to do with this.

I know my doubts are a bit childish (I started calculus a few weeks ago) but this is really messing with me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of $f^{n+1}$, it should be $f^{(n+1)}$.

Comment: Thanks, already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not supposed to compute that integral and, yes, it is the same $x$.

Suppose that you want to compute $\frac1e$ with great accuracy. You can do it using Taylor polynomials with that formula for the remainder. First of all, note that $\frac1e=\exp(-1)$. So, for any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, you have\begin{align}\frac1e&=\exp(-1)\\&=1-1+\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+R_n(-1).\end{align}So, you want to have a very small $|R_n(-1)|$. But\begin{align}|R_n(-1)|&=\left|\frac1{n!}\int_0^{-1}(-1-t)^n\exp^{(n+1)}(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\\&=\frac1{n!}\left|\int_{-1}^0(-1-t)^ne^t\,\mathrm dt\right|\\&\leqslant\frac1{n!}\int_{-1}^0|t+1|^ne^t\,\mathrm dt\\&\leqslant\frac1{n!}\end{align}since, for each $t\in[-1,0]$, both $|t+1\$ and $e^t$ are smaller than or equal to $1$.

Therefore, if you want to have a numerical approximation of $\frac1e$ with an error smaller than, say, $\frac1{1000}$, just take $n=7$. That will do, since $n!>1000$. So,$$\frac1e\approx\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\cdots-\frac1{7!}=\frac{103}{280}$$and the error is smaller that $\frac1{1000}$.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, thank you very much. Nevertheless, I would like to clarify some points. Can you redirect me to a simple proof for the $\left |\int f(x) dx \right | \leq \int |f(x)|dx $? And how can one conclude that $f(x) \leq 0 \Rightarrow \int f(x) dx \leq 0$?

Comment: Since $-f(x)\leqslant|f(x)|\leqslant f(x)$, you have$$-\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b-f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$and therefore$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Concerning your other question, if you always have $f(x)\leqslant0$, then every upper sum of $f$ is smaller than or equal to $0$ and so the integral is also smaller than or equal to $0$.

Comment: The last one graphically was really obvious, I don't know how could that escape me =) Agradecido!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: $-f(x)\leqslant|f(x)|\leqslant f(x)$ should of course be $-|f(x)|\leqslant f(x)\leqslant|f(x)|$.

Comment: @metamorphy Sure. Unfortunately, I cannot edit my comment anymore.

Comment: One last question. Because "t" will be substituted by the variable x, doesn't the expression $(x-t)^{n}$ equals zero? (x-x = 0, in this case, -1+1)

Comment: No. Suppose that $x=1$. Then what we have here is $\int_0^1(1-t)f^{(n+1)}(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Why would this be $0$?

Comment: I see. But then what is $t$? How can we conclude anything about $(1-t)^{n}$?

Comment: In my example, I used the fact that $t\in[0,1]$ to deduce that $|(1-t)^n|\leqslant1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you know $t$ in on that interval? Because of the definite integral?

Comment: Yes; it's an integral from $-1$ to $0$.